# Choosing the proper axes to compute Keras loss over

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm interested in using the CosineSimilarity loss function in Keras while training a neural network. My model is a multi-task model that forms 49 predictions per input. With a batch size of 10, the outputs will have shape = (10,49). Looking at the documentation, Keras computes this loss over a single axis only. However, my loss value is always a scalar, whereas I expect a 1D vector if the loss is computed over a single axis of a 2D output tensor. My loss value also differs slightly depending on whether I choose to compute the loss over axis = 0 or axis = 1, so I think the decision of which axis to use is important.

Can someone help me understand (1) why is the loss a scalar and not a 1D vector and (2) What is the difference in the interpretation of the loss value and what the model is attempting to optimize, if I compute the loss over the batch axis (axis = 0) versus the multi-task axis (axis = 1). (3) I want the model to be sensitive to small differences between data points in the batch, does this mean I should compute the loss over axis = 0? Also (4) why does keras compute the loss over axis = -1 by default (see the link the to the documentation to see this is the case)?

**More specifically:** If I compute the loss over the 0th axis, is keras computing the cosine similarity between each of the 49 vectors of shape (10,) in y_true and y_pred? If so, I am confused why i do not have 49 loss values. And if I compute the loss over the 1st axis, is keras computing the cosine similarity separately for each sample in the batch (i.e, comparing the (49,) y_pred and (49,) y_true for each of the 10 data points in the batch)? If so, I expect 10 loss values, but I only see a scalar. And most importantly: how would choosing one versus the other affect what the model is trying to optimize, particularly since a scalar is returned in either case, and given that I want the model to be sensitive to small differences between samples in a batch, does that mean I should compute the loss over axis = 0? My reasoning for choosing axis = 0 is that the cosine similarity is being taken between y_pred and y_true vectors that contain all samples in a batch (but for only 1 of the 49 tasks), whereas choosing axis = 1 would use vectors that contain each of the 49 outputs but for only 1 sample at a time.

I am concerned that I do not fully understand what my loss is doing. I want to customize my loss function in the future by building off of the cosine similarity, so it is important I understand exactly what is happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.